# Using Macbook touchpad (or others) for multi touch gestures in desktop browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, browser, multi-touch

I've looked around a bit but couldn't find a conclusive answer. Is it possible to detect multi touch gestures and events from a Macbook touchpad or other laptop trackpads in regular desktop browsers.

Let's say I want to click the touchpad and then scroll (a kind of dragscroll), but only when there is an extra finger touching the touchpad, instead of a regular dragscroll where the button is hold and then a single finger slides around.

It would be best if there was a generic API for this which worked with any laptop trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect multi touch gestures and events from a Macbook touchpad or other laptop trackpads in regular desktop browsers.

Unfortunately, no.

In theory, the [Touch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) is probably how this would be supported. However, desktop browsers only implement this API for devices with true touch screens (like a tablet or smartphone), not for trackpads.

Additionally, many laptops simply do not have trackpads which can track multiple touch points. This functionality is relatively uncommon outside of Apple laptops.